How do you test delegated listeners with JQuery, JSDOM, and Jest?
I have Jest and JSDOM set up to run tests for a JQuery app.  I have this test for what happens when you update a parent question that
should add a class to a change question.
HTML
<div>
    <div id="217ec445" data-child="445217ec">
        <select>
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="445217ec">
        <input/>
    </div>
</div>

JS App
function _parentsChangeHandler(){
    const $el = $(event.currentTarget);
    const childId = $el.data('child');
    if ($el.val() === 'Yes') {
        $(`#${childId}`).addClass('isHidden');
    } else {
        $(`#${childId}`).removeClass('isHidden');
    }
}
$('#217ec445').on('change', 'select', _parentsChangeHandler);

Tests:
const updatedValue = 'Yes';
// Parent Question
$('#217ec445').find('select').val(updatedValue);
$('#217ec445').find('select')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); // manually trigger change

// Child Question
const isHidden = $('#1ff03b89').hasClass('isHidden');
expect(isHidden).toBeFalsy();

This test fails when the code in the JS app is written with a delegated listener like this:
$('#217ec445').on('change', 'select', _parentsChangeHandler);

However, the test passes when the code is written with a normal listener like this:
$('#217ec445').find('select').on('change', _parentsChangeHandler);

Due to the dynamic HTML of the app (not shown in this example), it needs to be a delegated listener. How do I get delegated listeners to work within Jest and JSDOM?
